# How to toggle between Light & Dark Mode in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios13, ios-darkmode

Most of the information I've found online is dealing with Xamarin Forms, Is it possible to toggle between Light & Dark Mode using only Xamarin.iOS?

I've added this piece of code to my ViewDidLoad Method in one of my controllers to change it to Dark Mode but I do not know how to toggle it back to Light mode if someone could please share some thoughts on how this could be done?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    UILabel fetchDataLabel;
    UIView loadingView;

    **this.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;**

    base.ViewDidLoad();
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `TraitCollectionDidChange` method to detect the change of `OverrideUserInterfaceStyle`, then update UI there:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        this.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;


        UIButton myButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
        myButton.Frame = new CGRect(25, 25, 300, 150);
        myButton.SetTitle("Change Dark Mode", UIControlState.Normal);
        myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

            this.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light;

        };

        View.Add(myButton);
    }

    public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
    {
        base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

        var UserInterfaceStyle = TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle;

        //Update your UI here
    }
}
```